# How to add methods to Slick tables?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'd like do perform something like that using Slick (I have updated to `3.0.0-M1`):

```
class MyTable extends Table[(Int, Int)](tag, "MyTable) {
   def a = column[Int]("a")
   def b = column[Int]("b")

   def * = (a, b)

   def total: Int = a + b   // That's THE thing
}
```

So that I can later perform:

```
val values = TableQuery[MyTable]
values.map(_.total)
```

Of course, I am stuck on the `total` method. The `total` method can be fairly complex (I have an application where it should compute the median of three counts), so I think it should be actual Scala code to be executed in the end.

How anything like this could be developed in Slick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you can express it using Slick, e.g.

```
def total/*: Column[Int]*/ = a + b
```

It will be run on the server side. Instead of placing it in the `Table` subclass, you can alternatively use an implicit class to patch on a method from the outside:

```
implicit class ExtendMyTable(t: MyTable){
  def total/*: Column[Int]*/ = t.a + t.b
}
```

It just needs to be in scope where you try to call `.total`. Or if you really need client-side Scala coding, extend the result type instead, e.g.

```
implicit class ExtendMyTableResult(t: (Int,Int)){
  def total/*: Int*/ = t._1 + t._2
}
```

And then do

```
TableQuery[MyTable].run.map(_.total)
```